# AttributeError at /files/

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

when I am going to implement tag field I am getting following error

> AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `tags` on serializer `CategorySerializers`.
>   The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Category` instance.
>   Original exception text was: 'Category' object has no attribute 'tags'.

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class FileUp(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='path')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.name
```

**serializers.py**

```
 class TagSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ['tag_name']


class FileSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FileUp
        fields = ['file']


class CategorySerializers(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    files = FileSerializers(source='file_set', many=True, read_only=True)
    tags = TagSerializers(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'files', 'tags']
        read_only_fields = ['tags']

def create(self, validated_data):
    files_data = self.context.get('view').request.FILES
    name = Category.objects.create(name=validated_data.get('name'))

    for file_data in files_data.values():
        FileUp.objects.create(name=name, file=file_data)

    return name
```

here is what I tried, I have put **Tag** in **Category** model but when I am going to add files I cannot add tags to it or select tags in the admin panel. But, If I add Tag to FileUp I am getting error above shown. How can I apply to Tag to FileUp? any help please?

Comment: In `CategorySerializers` have you tried  using **tags** in same way you've used `files` field. try `tags=TagSerializers(source='tags_set', many=True)`

Comment: @xxbinxx There is no direct relation b/w tags and category

Answer (score 1):

Use **`SerializerMethodField`** parameter,

```
class CategorySerializers(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    files = FileSerializers(source='file_set', many=True, read_only=True)
    tags = serializers.SerializerMethodField() 

    def get_tags(self, category):
        return TagSerializers(Tag.objects.filter(fileup__name__categories=category), many=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'files', 'tags']
        read_only_fields = ['tags']
```

Comment: unfortunately it did not work now I have error Category object has not attr 'tag_set', additionally I have a create method please look above. I added some changes to it anyway it does not work

Comment: Related Field got invalid lookup: categories
this error shows. when i type till fileup__name is fine but if i am going to add __categories it does not recognize

Comment: it finally works i changed categories to name then it worked. Please can you explain what you did? if possible I am a bit confused of this kind of method. I did not use before